# How to center focused element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code below focuses on second element using javascript however the focused element sticks to bottom of page. I want to have focused element in the center of page how to do that?

```js
$(function(){
    $("#two").focus();
});
```

```css
body{color:white;}
#fis{height:600px;width: 60px;background-color:red;}
#two{height:50px;width: 60px;background-color:green;}
#thr{height:600px;width: 60px;background-color:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="fis">hello
    </div>
    <div id='two' tabindex='1'>mr
    </div>
    <div id='thr'>john
    </div>
```

Comment: Vertical centered, horizontal centered, fixed?

Comment: @GermanoPlebani vertically, as I said element for now sticks to bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS to select the focused element and then scroll the window to it :

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $(element_focused).offset().top
}, 300);
```

With a little math you can calculate the center of the element focused and change the `scrollTop` value.

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin:0 auto;` left/right margins to `auto` to center the element horizontally:

```js
$(function(){
    $("#two").focus().addClass('getCentered');
});
```

```css
body{color:white;}
#fis{height:600px;width: 60px;background-color:red;}
#two{height:50px;width: 60px;background-color:green;}
#thr{height:600px;width: 60px;background-color:blue;}
.getCentered{margin:0 auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="fis">hello
    </div>
    <div id='two' tabindex='1'>mr
    </div>
    <div id='thr'>john
    </div>
```

And if you want it always available in the center of the screen horizontally and vertically even with scroll, you can use `fixed` position with some calculations. check the snippet below center calculation with css:

```js
$(function(){
    $("#two").focus().addClass('getCentered');
});
```

```css
body{color:white;}
#fis{height:600px;width: 60px;background-color:red;}
#two{height:50px;width: 60px;background-color:green;}
#thr{height:600px;width: 60px;background-color:blue;}
.getCentered{position:fixed; left:50%; top:50%; margin:-25px 0 0 -30px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="fis">hello
    </div>
    <div id='two' tabindex='1'>mr
    </div>
    <div id='thr'>john
    </div>
```

Comment: I think OP need vertical center

Comment: may be @ketan but OP has to respond on answers or edit the question about it.

Comment: yes i just needed vertical center, as i said focused element sticks to bottom of page. I want to have focused element in the center of page; how can I make it happen without position fixed?